# How to rename a File via a batch-file but keep the file extention

Tags: batch-file, rename, filenames, file-extension

I have **several files** like that:

```
File1.txt
File2.txt
...
FileN.txt
```

and an executable **myExe.exe** that takes each one of these files and returns a txt-file with another name but keeps the extention.

```
( e.g. File1.txt --> File1_out.txt)
( e.g. File2.txt --> File2_out.txt)
( e.g. File3.txt --> File3_out.txt)
```

I want to run this in a **batch-file**.

I can add an x at the end of the extention (File1.txt-> File1.txt**x** )  using the following command :

```
for /r %%v in (*.txt) do myExe.exe "%%v"  "%%vx"
```

but I cannot rename the file.

**How would I rename the file and keep the extention?**

Comment: read the modifiers section in `for /?` - it tells you exactly how to get the basename, drive, path and extension separately.